Prometheus dockerswarm_sd_config + relabel_configs and routing mesh
Referring to Prometheus documentation on dockerswarm_sd_config here they suggest using this relabel_configs configuration for collecting nodes metrics:
relabel_configs:
      # Fetch metrics on port 9323.
      - source_labels: [__meta_dockerswarm_node_address]
        target_label: __address__
        replacement: $1:9323

It looks an error to me: with this config, I think I'm leveraging swarm routing mesh, so any time Prometheus tries to scape a node, it asks to the node IP address and in turns it gets a random host from the swarm. In other words, it looks to me Prometheus believes scraping Node1 but its request is forwarded to any node the mesh decides.
Sure Prometheus documentation is fine, so, were I'm wrong?
Thanks.

__meta_dockerswarm_node_address is build with the node IPs. It never goes over a routing mesh. There is no routing mesh for nodes.

Thank you. However the routing mesh seems to be used during my tests. Also, this page https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/ingress/  states: "The routing mesh listens on the published port for any IP address assigned to the node".  __meta_dockerswarm_node_address seems to fall in this category. Moreover, I created and globally deployed a node app exposing the hostname on a particular route; if I refresh the browser pointing to this route using the first node IP, I often see the hostanem changing: this looks to me the routing mesh serving different containers using node IPs.

:9323 is the port that docker will publish prometheus metrics to when experimental is enabled. the listener should be the dockerd on the node itself, so there is no routing mesh involved. This only makes sense with role: nodes as you want to fetch docker metrics from each node.

converserly, with role: service, you can choose to scrape services using a published port (and node ip), or actual port (and overlay ip). as actual ports are not configured anywhere (except as the target for a published port) there is no way for prometheus to know them so you need to supply them. Published ports conversely only exist on the routing mesh/ingress network so you can't scrape individual tasks  (without doing undesirable things like turning on mode: host networking)

Thank you, now the difference between node ad service roles is much more clear to me!

Docker swarm service discovery operates in 3 roles: nodes, tasks and services.
nodes and services roles generate a service discovery endpoint for every published port, or, if there are no published ports they synthesise entries for each docker network the service/task is attached to and use the default port.
So, you can define prometheus config like this to scrape from all services attached to an overlay network :- This config discards all service entries that are not attached to the prometheus network, and optionally rewrites the scrape address to use a service label provided port.
- job_name: 'dockerswarm'
  dockerswarm_sd_configs:
  - host: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    role: tasks
    port: 9090
  relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__meta_dockerswarm_network_name]
    regex: prometheus-network
    action: keep
  - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_dockerswarm_service_label_prometheus_metrics_port]
    regex: '(.*):(\d+);(\d+)'
    target_label: __address__
    replacement: "$1:$3"

To scrape services using this config, define them like this: We allow the prometheus service to be scraped with the default of 9090 .
compose.yml
networks:
  prometheus-network:
    external: true

services:
  prometheus:
    networks: prometheus-network
    ...
  cadvisor:
    networks: prometheus-network
    ...
    deploy:
      labels:
        prometheus.metrics.port: 8080


This approach, of course, correctly assigns each pool of metrics to a discreet IP.
If you have a need to track logical instances, then use the hostname of the underlying node, or track by task id:
compose.yml
services:
  etcd:
    hostname: etcd-{{.Node.Hostname}}
    ...
  minio:
    hostname: minio{{.Task.Slot}}

Then grab the hostname and assign it to a new label.
prometheus.yaml
...
    relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__meta_dockerswarm_service_task_container_hostname]
      target_label: node_hostname
# Or go direct to instance
#      target_label: instance


Thank you, I agree with you that using address will work and will not leverage routing mesh. However I need to relabel from address (i.e. 10.0.0.x) to __meta_dockerswarm_node_address (i.e. 192.168.x.y) in order to ignore container IP changes. This is useful for instance in grafana when analizing node-exporter metrics when node-exporter is hosted inside a container and it will change _address after any re-deploy. Using relabel_configs plus port mapping with mode=host (as described in the prometheus documentation) seems to work now.

forcing host mode imposes a number of artificial side effects that adding monitoring really should not incur.

I finally found the solution by better reading Prometheus documentation.
Indeed, with default services configuration, VIP produces incorrect values as I decribed in the question.
However, inside Prometheus documentation it is specified that the services must use port mapping mode='host' in order to eliminate the routing mesh (bypassing VIP)
For instance:
ports:
  - target: 9100
    published: 9100
    mode: host

Using this port mapping now it is working as expected.
